# mod_vhost_alias and sudomains not working

Tags: php, apache

i have problem with **mod_vhost_alias** mod in apache2. I have use this configuration to domains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName *
UseCanonicalName Off
ServerAlias *
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0
</VirtualHost>
```

But with this configuration dont working domain with www.

If i use this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName *
UseCanonicalName Off
ServerAlias *
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-2.0.%-1.0/
</VirtualHost>
```

domain with www working but dont working subdomains!!

Anyone help me please? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that. Specify the domains for your ServerName and Alias.

When you set a wildcard for your **ServerName** and your **ServerAlias** both auf them listen to the same. Thats not working. And i think the specification can't handle an asterisk for the ServerName.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/de/mod/core.html#servername

The Documentation says for the **ServerName**

```
Syntax: ServerName voll-qualifizierter-Domainname[:port]
```

So you should define your ServerName. In Your ServerAlias you can use a Wildcard.

https://serverfault.com/questions/139628/servername-wildcards-in-apache-name-based-virtual-hosts